# Can not intercept Android view method call using Byte Buddy and Android Buddy. How can I do that?

Tags: java, android, byte-buddy, bytecode-manipulation, byte-code-enhancement

I want to intercept android view class method call. For example inside view class there is a method name getHeight(). So when from my code obj.getHeight() will call I want to intercept that and want to return an arbitary value.

I can intercept my own class method call. But could not do that with android view class.
I am using Android Buddy which is using Byte Buddy. So here is my code

```
object ViewMethodInterceptor {

    @JvmStatic
    fun intercept(@SuperCall originalMethodCall: Runnable): Int  {
        Log.i("myTag", "Intercepted View Class getHeight ")
        return 500;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for ViewTransformation plugin.

```
@Transformation
class ViewTransformation : Plugin {

    override fun apply(
        builder: DynamicType.Builder<*>,
        typeDescription: TypeDescription,
        classFileLocator: ClassFileLocator
    ): DynamicType.Builder<*> {
        return builder.method(ElementMatchers.named("getHeight"))
            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(ViewMethodInterceptor::class.java))
    }

    override fun matches(target: TypeDescription): Boolean {
        return target.isAssignableTo(View::class.java)
    }


    override fun close() {
        // Nothing to close
    }
}
```

and I am calling the getHeight() method from the onCreate method of my MainActivity.

Comment: Is there a log that shows you what classes are transformed?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter could not finding anything.

Comment: I assume that there is some debug logging in the plugin. I did however not write it, so I would not know. Did you try running Gradle with *--debug*?